# 2 bit branch predictor with two for loops

Tags: cpu-architecture, branch-prediction

I got a 2 bit branch predictor, my starting state is weakly taken and I need to calculate the prediction accuracy:

```
for (int i=0; i < 100; i++)
{
   for (int j=0; j < 50; j++)
   {
   ...
   }
}
```

So with i = 0 we take the branch, so we are at i = 0 and j = 0 and set our predictor to strongly taken, right ? So if we iterate j now, does that mean we are not taking a new branch ? As we are still in the i = 0 branch, or does every iteration count as a new branch ?

Comment: Try to make clear that it is about branch prediction. Other my read this and don't understand that this is a clear defined topic...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's manually compile it into x86 assembly first for better understanding (any other would do to):

```
    mov ebx, 0        // this is our var i
.L0:
# /------------ inner loop start -----------\ 
    mov eax, 0        // this is our var j
.L1: 
    // ...
    add     eax, 1
    cmp     eax, 50
    jl      .L1       // jump one
# \------------ inner loop end -------------/
    add     ebx, 1
    cmp     ebx, 100
    jl      .L0       // jump two
```

I think this code is pretty straight forward even if your not familiar with assembly:

- Set *ebx* to `0`
- *jump two gets back here*

  - Set *eax* to `0`
  - *jump one gets back here*

    - Execute our loop code `// ...`
    - add `1` to *eax*
    - compare *eax* to `50` (this sets some bits in a flag register)
    - jump to label `.L1:` if eax wasn't 50
  - add `1` to *ebx*
  - compare *ebx* to `50` (this sets some bits in a flag register)
  - jump to label `.L0:` if ebx wasn't 100
- *End of the loops*

So on the first iteration we arrive at *jump one* and predict it will be taken. Since `eax < 50` we take it and update it to *strongly taken*. Now we do this another 48 times. On the 50 iteration we don't jump because `eax == 50`. This is a **single misprediction** and we update to weakly taken.

Now we arrive at *jump two* for the first time. since `ebx < 100` we take it and update it to *strongly taken*. Now we start all over with that inner loop by jumping to `L0`. We do this another 98 times. On the 100 iteration of the inner loop we don't jump because `ebx == 100`. This is a **single misprediction** and we update to weakly taken.

So we execute the innerloop *100 times* with a *single misprediction* each for a total of **100 mispredictions** for *jump one* and *`100 * 49 = 4900` correct predictions*. The outer loop is executed only once and has only **1 misprediction** and *`99` correct predictions*.

Comment: I'm sorry for my late reply I totally forgot checking up on this as I already wrote the exam, but I will need it again next semester. So thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @lllllIIIIll Feel free to upvote it if you think its a good answer ;)